# Como verificar variáveis com jQuery para que não sejam enviadas vazias?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu estou aprendendo sobre jQuery e já comecei a fazer requisições Ajax para cadastrar as informações no banco de dados mysql. Tenho um código que possui várias variáveis e gostaria de perguntar como posso verificar de uma só vez se existe alguma variável vazia. Estava pensando em fazer isso com array mas não sei como usar. Estas variáveis serão capturadas a partir do submit do formulário. Peço ajuda!

```
    var empresa;        
    var username;       
    var ativado;            
    var tipousuario;        
    var senha;              
    var nome;               
    var cpf;                
    var cnpj;
```

Comment: Você pode usar o if como visto [nessa resposta][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6003920

Comment: Colocaria elas num if e verificaria uma por uma retornando uma resposta única ou faria vários if's com uma resposta personalizada para cada variável certo?

Comment: verifica no server side e retorna a mensagem de erro pra mostrar no ajax.

Comment: Pode validar no JS, mas inevitavelmente vai precisar validar TAMBÉM com PHP, já que o JS pode estar desabilitado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por vezes faz-se validação no lado do cliente e no lado do servidor. Tem sempre várias maneiras de o fazer.

Para fazer uma verificação no lado cliente vai ter de procurar por `element.value`, `element.checked` dependendo do tipo de elemento, e no caso de `input type="radio"` tem de percorrer todos e ver se um deles está selecionado. Pode facilitar um pouco juntando uma classe a esses elementos, mas senão teste assim:

```
var validado = true, erros = 0;
$('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
    var nomeTag = this.tagName.toLowerCase()
    if (nomeTag == 'select' || nomeTag == 'textarea') validado = !!this.value;
    else if (this.type == 'checkbox') validado = !!this.checked;
    else if (this.type == 'radio') validado = !!$('input').filter(function () {
        return this.checked
    })[0];
    else validado = !!this.value

    if (!validado) {
        this.addClass('incompleto');
        erros++;
    } else {
        this.removeClass('incompleto');
    }
});
if (erros) // validacao falhou!
```

Se o `erros` não der `0` depois deste código então há campos vazios. Juntei uma parte opcional para dar uma classe aos elementos vazios para visibilidade do utilizador.

No lado do PHP todos os campos vão dentro do $_GET ou $_POST, depende como está a usar. Aí pode fazer uma verificação simples com um ciclo for:

```
foreach ($post as $chave=>$valor) if (!$valor) die('O campo '.$chave.' está  vazio!');
```

Existem métodos mais complexos para verificar o tipo de conteudo. Nestes exemplos, e na sequencia do que perguntou, isto só verifica se há campos vazios.

Atênção: esta verificação não faz nada no sentido de fazer o conteudo seguro, ou seja esta verificação deve seguir-se de outra que prepara o conteudo para ser inserido na base de dados.