# Verificar variaveis em jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Existe uma forma mais inteligente de escrever este código de verificação, o `IF`?

```
    jQuery("#oformulario").submit(function(){

        var nome            = jQuery("#nome").val();
        var email           = jQuery("#email").val();
        var telefone        = jQuery("#telefone").val();
        var tipodecontato   = jQuery("#tipodecontato").val();
        var mensagem        = jQuery("#mensagem").val();
        var send            = jQuery("#send").attr("name");

        if(nome != "" && email != "" && telefone != "" && tipodecontato != "" && mensagem != "" && send == "enviar"){
```

Answer (score 3):

Se quer fazer uma validação "simples", ie só verificar se o input está vazio ou não pode fazer assim:

```
if(!$('form').serialize().match(/=&|=$/)) { // correr código
```

#### Exemplo:  http://jsfiddle.net/xr5z2rnp/1/

O que o .serialize() faz é transformar o input numa string que pode ser passada para o ajax por exemplo.

Nessa string, vao pares chave|valor (`chave=valor`), onde cada par é separado por `&`. Ora isso quer dizer que se houver um igual (`=`) seguido de `&` entao há uma valor vazio! Usei o operador de negação (`!`) pois havendo um `=&` na string o match dá true, com o `!` inverto para false. Juntei também `=$` que procura pelo sinal de igual como ultimo caracter da string.

Se está a usar ajax, pode fazer assim:

```
var meudata = $('form').serialize();
if(!meudata.match(/=&|=$/)) { // fazer ajax
```

e no campo `data` data do ajax, faz `data: meudata,`.

Se quiser fazer uma validação mais detalhada, a minha [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28105/129) pode ajudar.

Comment: tem um pequeno bug, o ultimo campo fica apenas = então mesmo não preenchendo ele a validação diz que esta true... outra dificuldade seria com possíveis campos não obrigatórios.

Comment: @Jader bem visto, obrigado. Juntei também `=$` para strings que acabam sem valor.

Answer (score 2):

Daria pra fazer algo assim:

```
$("#oformulario").submit(function(){
    var erro = false;
    $(this).find('input:not(.campo-nao-obrigatorio)').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') erro = true;
    });

        if(erro == false && $("#send").attr("name") == "enviar") {
```

não precisaria declarar todos os campos do formulário...