# Validação de select

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte HTML

```
<select class="cadastroDireitaInput cadastroSiteSexo" id="sexo" name="sexo">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="Feminino">Feminino</option>
  <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
</select>
```

Tenho um JS que verifica se os campos estão preenchidos, como por exemplo, essa linha de código:

```
if($.trim($('#nomeFormUS').val())=='')alert('Informe seu nome!');
```

Nesse caso, ele verifica se um input está preenchido.

Agora, como eu verifico se foi selecionado algum Option desse Select?

Comment: É a mesma coisa, com jQuery.val().

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema?

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso deste jeito:

```
<script>
if(nome_formuario.nome_do_select.selectedIndex==0){
            alert("Informe o status do contrato");
            form.st_contrato.focus();
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o `.val()` também ou usar javascript puro `.value`

Dê uma olhada a este exemplo que faz alert de "false" quando escolhe a primeira opção e "true" nas outras:

```
$('#sexo').on('change', function(){
    $('#resultado').text(!!this.value);
});
```

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/jwgu6on1/)

Assim o seu código poderia ser: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/hjvmLh7s/1/))

```
 if(!this.value) alert('Informe seu sexo!');
```

Comment: Se eu quiser que ele apenas verifique se está ou não marcado, sem mostrar. É só remover o `$('#resultado').text(!!this.value + ' ' + this.value);`?

Comment: @FelipeStoker, fiz update: `if(!this.value) alert('Informe seu sexo!');`

Comment: É só aqui que o Fiddle não abre há semanas?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto o jsFidle tem estado a receber um upgrade. Aqui na suécia já funciona

Comment: @Sergio, só uma dúvida. Como ficaria a sintaxe, seguindo essa minha estrutura? Ele funfou de boas no seu exemplo, mas devo ter incluído ele errado.
http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/nnfvge9f/

Comment: @FelipeStoker coloque aqui um fiddle com o HTML e posso mostrar uma maneira bem mais simples.

Comment: @FelipeStoker na verdade começo a pensar que a sua pergunta é bem parecida com esta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28085/129

Comment: @Sergio, cara eu criei confusão. A sua resposta me ajudou, mas percebi que posso usar igual usei nos outros:
Exemplo `    else if($.trim($('#sexo').val())=='')alert('Informe o seu sexo!');
` Eu só quero que ele veja se está ou não marcada a opção. Valeu :)

Comment: @FelipeStoker, você está a fazer mais complicado do que precisa. É sempre melhor usar javascript puro do que jQuery. Se quiser colocar o HTML posso ajudar a simplificar.

Answer (score 1):

mas o correto seria já você trazer como padrão algum sexo ... problema simples e a menos para se preocupar

```
  $('#sexo').change(function(){
       var value = $(this).val();
          if(value == ''){
            alert('Escolha um sexo');        
        }
    });
```